# Convert ID to Username using JSON

Tags: json, swift

I have two JSON call functions that get clients data and invoice data. In my clients JSON response I have ID and name, etc. In my invoice response I have client ID.

I need to get the client ID from invoice and convert to the client name string.

In my `ClientsViewController` I've made a function called `downloadClientsJSON`

```
func downloadClientsJSON(completed: @escaping () -> ()) {
    let url = URL(string: "http://ex.com/app/api/clientList/get")

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, response, error) in
        if error == nil {
            do {
                self.clients.removeAll()
                self.clients = try JSONDecoder().decode([ClientsList].self, from: data!)

                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    completed()
                }
            } catch {
                print ("Error")
            }
        }
    }.resume()
}
```

And here is the `ClientsList` structure:

```
import Foundation

struct ClientsList:Decodable {
   let name: String
   let vatNumber: String
   let address: String
   let cap: String
   let city: String
   let prov: String
   let tel: String
   let email: String
}
```

Here is the JSON Response:

```
[{"id":1,"name":"DemoClient","vatNumber":"010101010101","address":"Demo Address, 1","cap":"01010","city":"DemoCity","prov":"DP","tel":"555-1112223","email":"demo@example.com"}]
```

In my `InvoiceViewController` I've made a function called `downloadInvoicesJSON`

```
func downloadJSON(completed: @escaping () -> ()) {
    let url = URL(string: "http://ex.com/app/api/invoiceList/get")

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, response, error) in
        if error == nil {
            do {
                self.invoices.removeAll()
                self.invoices = try JSONDecoder().decode([InvoiceList].self, from: data!)

                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    completed()
                }
            } catch {
                print (error)
            }
        }
    }.resume()
}
```

Here is the `InvoiceList` structure:

```
import Foundation

struct InvoiceList:Decodable {
    let id: NSInteger
    let date: String
    let expiration: String
    let client: NSInteger
    let status: NSInteger
    let lines: String
    let total: Float
}
```

Here is the JSON Response:

```
[{"id":1,"date":"01-01-2018","expiration":"01-01-2018","client":3,"status":3,"lines":"1:1","total":700},{"id":2,"date":"30-01-2018","expiration":"30-01-2018","client":4,"status":2,"lines":"1:1","total":100},{"id":3,"date":"15-02-2018","expiration":"15-02-2018","client":3,"status":3,"lines":"1:1","total":700}]
```

The function should be in the `InvoiceViewController`. How do I get the result?

Comment: Can you print JSON data as well, because you need to create struct with properties same as JSON parameter keys.

Answer (score 0):

JSON object you are getting from `http://ex.com/app/api/clientList/get` should be an array and parameter keys should be same as property name of `ClientsList`.

```
struct ClientsList: Decodable {
    let name: String
    let vatNumber: String
    let address: String
    let cap: String
    let city: String
    let prov: String
    let tel: String
    let email: String
}
```

If you are not sure that you will receive all properties in the response JSON, then make that particular property optional. like:

```
struct ClientsList: Decodable {
    let name: String
    let vatNumber: String
    let address: String
    let cap: String
    let city: String? // Not sure about receiving this property
    let prov: String? // Not sure about receiving this property
    let tel: String? // Not sure about receiving this property
    let email: String
}
```

Same pattern you need to follow for `http://ex.com/app/api/invoiceList/get` and `InvoiceList`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I didn't check if i will receive these values cause all the json post calls for putting data fails if I don't send all the data in that format. All data where stored as string instead of should be integer (as telephone number, cause we can have 0 in front of number)